# Linux device left open

Tags: c, linux

I was debugging on a Single Board Computer, and I figured out that I never closed the ttyUSB in my program. Now the program will not get past the open() function. How can I manually close the line, or force it open? I would prefer not to shutdown the computer, and the USB device must remain in the SBC.

The specific line that I am having trouble with is:

```
gpso = open(GPSDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY); //gps device is the directory name of the device (ttyUSB0)
```

Comment: Can you run `fuser` or `lsof` to discover if any processes still have the file open? Kill those processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At process termination the kernel automatically closes all filehandles.

If the devices is still opened it means that the process is still running. Kill it.

Comment: I forgot about my BG processes. Thank you.